# Refused Canada Business visa with 21 visas in my passports

Tags: visas, canada, business-travel, nigerian-citizens

I was refused a Canada Business visa. They said the reasons were: travel history, purpose of travel, and funds. I was shocked because I have 21 visas in the last eight years in three passports:

- 3off 2-years USA (one still valid),
- 2off UK (one still valid 10-years),
- 10off Schenghen (all Germany),
- South Africa, Dubai, Brazil, 2off China, and Qatar.

All visas were used. I have travelled out of my country, Nigeria, more than 35 times.  In my introduction letter I stated my travel plan. I want to visit the USA then a conference in Canada for four days. I also had my invitation letter and bank statements with at least $4,000.

Why was I refused?

What can I do now?

I provided all the check list required, would add refusal page now

[image]

Comment: Basically they rejected you on every criteria. Was your bank statement from a blacklisted bank? Your case off the bat sounds like one of the more unreasonable refusals, unless they gave some specific reasons. It's going to be really tough for anyone to decipher what exactly is the problem since they checked off three broad refusal criteria.

Comment: Unfortunately, Canada visa refusals are very nearly inscrutable.

Comment: We cannot say for sure without seeing the documents you've sumbitted and the Canadian visa refusal. What you've described doesn't provide any clues to why you could've been refused.

Comment: @Fatunle Thanks for providing the visa refusal. Unfortunately unlike UK visa refusals which give specific explanation why you were refused, Canada only provides this broad checklist. We will just be guessing if we try to nail down exactly what the problem was. I recommend you get an immigration attorney to handle your next application. Also despite your impressive immigration history, in your next application don't assume you can cut corners on supporting documents. Consular officers can be funny. It is always better if you apply with everything, as if you are a new traveler. Take no chances.